# Can I use OAuth2 on GDAX Api?

Tags: api, oauth-2.0, gdax-api

I would like to create an app that is connected to your GDAX account.

I saw on GDAX docs that we can connect our account to the api https://docs.gdax.com/#authentication. But that is done manually, you have to go to your own GDAX account https://www.gdax.com/settings/api and generate keys then link those keys.

That process is not possible if I want to create an app for publics. Is there a way to connect my app through OAuth2 ? Like you could do with facebook ok twitter ?

Answer (score 0):

not currently possible. The secret, api key and passphrase are all used to sign requests and make API calls, rather than for oauth access.